# How to exclude one item in a list from a CSV file and print the rest of he row on a seperare file?

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm trying to print convert a row in a CSV file to a list depending on the user input of the "rater id", then print out each item of that row except when there is a 99 in the row. When I run this it doesn't print anything out. Can anyone help where I'm going wrong?
Thanks!

```
file = open("movies-wk5-ratings.csv")
rater_id = int(input("Type a rater ID between 1 and 
7699")) 
for data in file:
  datalist = data.split (",")
  data_rating = datalist[2:]
  print([d for d in data_rating if d!='99'])
```

Comment: May I ask what this line is expected to do: `if rater_id == datalist [0] !=99:`  I’m surprised syntax errors aren’t thrown.  The presence of two comparison operators is not correct; perhaps why there is no output.

Comment: hmm okay I am new to using python so I have just ben trying out different things, I am trying to print all items in a list corresponding to the number the user input, so I need everything after the first 2 items and excluding 99

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Also, please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

The condition in your if statement is not valid, or at least it doesn't do what you want.
If I understand correctly, I think you should do something like this :

```
if rater_id == datalist[0] and datalist[0] != 99:
    print(rater_id)
```

Edit:
As S3DEV said in the comments, a newer and more pythonic way to do this is with `all()`:

```
if all([rater_id == datalist[0], datalist[0] != 99]):
    print(rater_id)
```

Comment: Consider replacing the old `and` syntax with the `all()` function.

Comment: Hey, I tried that out but it's still printing blank. I can try and explain it better, I am trying to print whatever line in a CSV file that the user input, then skip the first 2 items in that line, and print everything else excluding the number 99. Does that make any sense? thank you :)

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.7' thank you! when I print that I am getting this erroe message, do you know what this means?

Answer (score 0):

`if rater_id == int(datalist[0]) and rater_id!=99:`

Comment: Try to add some explanation of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the csv in a pandas dataframe and index it, do simple check on row and return.

I am still confused after reading your code.
what are the first 2 elements of the row?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('name.csv')
df.iloc[rate_id] # will help you extract the row
```

OR

```
for data in file:
  datalist = data.split (",")
  data_rating = datalist[2:]
  print([d for d in data_rating if d!='99']) # I am doing this as the csv might read the input as strings
```

Comment: This commentary would be better placed as a comment, as it does not offer an explicit solution. Or, consider providing a solution.

Comment: the first 2 elements are names of people and not the actual data I am supposed to print, so i need everything after the first 2 items and excluding 99

Comment: @sophiezapalowska You want to return the row associated with the rater_id? And if that row contains a 99 you return an empty list??

Comment: return the row associated with the rater id yes but then print everything in the row except for 99. pretty much the row consists of ratings, and if there is a 99 in a column it's a placeholder for no rating so I don't want to print that, just everything else.

Comment: @sophiezapalowska updated my answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @ShivangiSingh i just updated my questions code adding this on, im getting  this error message            ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal 
for the second line of the code. Do you know why?

Comment: Try the csv package

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things:

1. A strange line-break on/after the first line (the assignment of `rater_id`)
2. It seems that `datalist[1]` is discarded / ignored; is that intentional? I leave that for now.
3. Assuming that each line *only* contains comma-separated numbers, you need to convert the numbers as strings into numbers as floats in order to perform proper number comparisons
4. The condition on the next to last line seems incorrect. I think you want to print the row of values when `rater_id` it is equal to the first element of the line **and** when there is no value of `99` in any element of the row
5. You only print the `rater_id` and not each item of each row matching the criteria. Given the `data_rating` assignment, you would perhaps like to print only that part of the record?

With the corrections, the script would be:

```py
rater_id = int(input("Type a rater ID between 1 and 7699")) 
file = open("file_name")
for data in file:
  datalist = [float(item) for item in data.split(",")]
  data_rating = datalist[2:]
  if rater_id == datalist[0] and 99 not in datalist:
    print(*data_rating, sep=", ")
```

If the first item of the line should still be an `int` instead of a `float` you need to adapt the script a little more. My assumption now is that it is possible to convert each item on the line into a floating point value.

Comment: thank you for the help I was confused where I was going wrong. when I print this I am now getting this error message, i tried float but then it prints blank with no error                                            
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 111, in <module>
    datalist = [int(item) for item in data.split(",")]
  File "main.py", line 111, in <listcomp>
    datalist = [int(item) for item in data.split(",")]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.7'

Comment: OK, apparently the line consists of `float` values; I will edit my answer to cater for that